# Getting ListView position with which user is interacting

Tags: android, listview, position, getview

I have a list of items that have a ToggleButton. The `position` might be 10, while a user can tap the ToggleButton of the next list item (which is not fully visible).

How can I get the position of that list item whose button is getting clicked by the user?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: Maybe you can set a tag with the position on the ToggleButton. Easier to tell if you show us what you've got so far

Answer (score 0):

you can add **OnItemClickListener** to your list view and listen to user interact with your list

```
yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
             // when user click on item the position will show as Toast 
             Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,position+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```